# Getting the other dates for a week with only a single date and DayOfWeek?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to build a table with the header of each column having both the day of the week as well as the date of that day (i.e. Sunday 02/02/16). My `ViewModel` has a `WeekEndingDate` and `DayOfWeek` property giving me a single date for that week to work with. I am unable to figure out how to extract the reset of the dates for that week.

`WeekEndingDate` will be the date of this week's Saturday (so for today 5/4/16 `WeekEndingDate` would be 5/7/16).

Here is my VM:

```
public class TimesheetWeeklyTableVM
{
    public int TimesheetHeaderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeekEndingDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalWeekHours { get; set; }

    public List<TimesheetDailyVM> DaysOfWeek { get; set; }

    public TimesheetWeeklyTableVM()
    {
        DaysOfWeek = new List<TimesheetDailyVM>();

        foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
        {
            DaysOfWeek.Add(new TimesheetDailyVM()
            {
                DayOfWeek = dayOfWeek
            });
        }
    }
}

public class TimesheetDailyVM
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public double TotalHours
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Tasks.Sum(p => (p.StartDateTime - p.EndDateTime).TotalSeconds)).TotalHours;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TimesheetDailyHoursVM> Tasks { get; set; }

    public TimesheetDailyVM()
    {
        Tasks = new List<TimesheetDailyHoursVM>();
    }
}

public class TimesheetDailyHoursVM
{
    public int TimesheetID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string TaskCode { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And the Razor code that will be generating the table:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Total Hours: <br />
                @Model.TotalWeekHours
            </th>
            @foreach (var day in Model.DaysOfWeek)
            {
                <th>
                    @day.DayOfWeek <br />
                    @Model.WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-(int)day.DayOfWeek).Date
                </th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I have tried `@Model.WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-(int)day.DayOfWeek).Date` but that gives me the error `PThe added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: value`

I also tried `@Model.WeekEndingDate.AddDays(-(int)day.DayOfWeek.ToString("d")).Date` since I know the `ToString("D")` method will generate a `int` value. But that gives the error `Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a whole week, you could start by getting the week number

```
public static int ToWeekNumber(this DateTime dtPassed)
{
    CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dtPassed, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    return weekNum;
}
```

This is an extension method to get the Date's week number (Based on the first four day week rule)

```
public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dayInWeek)
{
    CultureInfo defaultCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    return Helpers.GetFirstDayOfWeek(dayInWeek, defaultCultureInfo);
}

 public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dayInWeek, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    DayOfWeek firstDay = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
    DateTime firstDayInWeek = dayInWeek.Date;
    while (firstDayInWeek.DayOfWeek != firstDay)
        firstDayInWeek = firstDayInWeek.AddDays(-1);

    return firstDayInWeek;
}
```

These two methods return the First day of the week. (Instead of the last one), based on the WeekNumber and the current culture. (In my culture "pt-BR", its sunday)

So on your Constructor you can do like this:

```
public TimesheetWeeklyTableVM(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime firstDay = Helpers.GetFirstDayOfWeek(date);
    DaysOfWeek = new List<TimesheetDailyVM>();

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        DaysOfWeek.Add(new TimesheetDailyVM()
        {
            MyCurrentDay = firstDay.AddDays(i);
        });
    }
}
```

And on your TimesheetDailyVM class add the following:

```
public DateTime MyCurrentDay { get; set; }
```

Your Razor Should look like this

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Total Hours: <br />
            @Model.TotalWeekHours
        </th>
        @foreach (var day in Model.DaysOfWeek)
        {
            <th>
                @day.MyCurrentDay.DayOfWeek <br />
                @day.MyCurrentDay.Date
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
</thead>
```